# One iOS App under Different provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

Stupid question but I'll ask anyway.

I have 2 iOS team provisioning profiles, but one of them is still processing. So when it finally activates, I'll have 2. Is it possible to

- Create the same App ID on both (when the other profile comes) and continue with development on the right one
- When distributing the App, use one of the profiles to release it?

From my understanding App ID has to be unique, so will it be a conflict from the provisioning profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are developing you can have as many `provisioning profile` as you want. (I have 3)
But this are developing profile.

When submitting an app you have to switch to `distribution profile` (you can choose one) but then you can submit always only with this one.

So you can develop with one profile, wait for process to complete, switch profile and only then submit your app.